# Python: how to use constructor with Django Form class?

Tags: python, django, constructor, django-forms

I want to pass parameters when initializing a Form class. I tried the following:

```
class BlogForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.default_text = kwargs.pop('text')
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget(), initial = default_text)
```

However, the `default_text` variable used in body field is out of scope. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `default_text` only inside of the `__init__` method.  To access the `body` field use the `self.fields` dict:

```
class BlogForm(forms.Form):

    body = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.default_text = kwargs.pop('text')
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['body'].initial = self.default_text
```

Comment: It gives an error: AttributeError: 'BlogForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: Every initialized form has the `fields` attribute.  Seems like you trying to access the `fields` before the calling of the `super(BlogForm, self).__init__()`.  Look at my code, I assign the `initial` **after** the `__init__` call.

Comment: It seems the body field is taking the initial value as declared in the statement before the constructor is defined i.e. the value of initial is null.

Comment: I tested the code from my answer and it works fine.  Initial data is set as expected. How do you instantiate the form?